# Displaying JSON data in particular cells of a table

Tags: javascript, json

I am totally new to JavaScript so apologies if I sound stupid. I am trying to loop over JSON and display data in a student timetable for which I need to send data to "particular cells". My current code given works just fine but looks a lot clunky and trivial. I just want to know if there is a better and efficient way of doing this instead of using loads of "if statements"?
Help would be much appreciated

```
function displayJSON() {
    for (var parkName in parksListJSON) {
        var park = parksListJSON[parkName];
        console.log(park);
    }

    var schedule = parksListJSON.schedule;

    for (var i = 0; i < schedule.length; i++){
        var schedule = parksListJSON.schedule;
        var moduleCode = schedule[i].module;
        var session = schedule[i].sessionType;

        if (!parksListJSON.schedule[i].allocatedTime) {
            var lecCode = schedule[i].module;
            var type = schedule[i].sessionType;
            var lecLocation = schedule[i].location;
            var fred = ('<td class="something"> ' + lecCode + ',<br> ' + type + '<br> ' + lecLocation + ' ' + '</td>' );

            if (moduleCode == "uh6com1051"){
                document.querySelector("#thurs .s15").innerHTML=fred
            }

            if (moduleCode == "uh6com1099"){
                document.querySelector("#fri .s12").innerHTML=fred
            }

            if (moduleCode == "uh6com1063"){
                document.querySelector("#tues .s12").innerHTML=fred
            }  
        }else
        { 
            var groupName = schedule[i].allocatedTime.group;
            var locations=schedule[i].allocatedTime.location;
            var array = [moduleCode,session,locations,groupName];
            var fred = ('<td class="something"> ' + array[0] +',<br> '+ array[1]+',<br> ' + array[2] +', ' + array[3] + '  ' +  '</td>' );

            if (moduleCode == "uh6com1051"){
                if (session == "tutorial"){  
                    document.querySelector("#weds .s9").innerHTML=fred;
                }
            }
            if (moduleCode == "uh6com1051"){
                if (session == "lab"){
                    document.querySelector("#mon .s11").innerHTML=fred;
                }
            }
            if (moduleCode == "uh6com1063"){
                if (session == "lab"){
                    document.querySelector("#tues .s11").innerHTML=fred;
                }
            }
            if (moduleCode == "uh6com1063"){
                if (session == "tutorial"){
                    document.querySelector("#mon .s13").innerHTML=fred;
                }
            }
            if (moduleCode == "uh6com1099"){
                if (session == "tutorial"){    
                    document.querySelector("#weds .s11").innerHTML=fred;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you show the JSON ? or better a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: why don't you use `switch` instead of `if`?

Comment: Here is the link to fiddle [ https://jsfiddle.net/KaleemShahid/u5mtq1ef/ ] @FlyingGambit

Comment: What is the difference between `allocatedTime` and `alternativeTimes`

Comment: Also, is it possible for you to change the JSON format if needed ?

Comment: 'allocatedTime' refers to students' personal timings for the certain module, whereas 'alternativeTimes' are those slots which are available for student other than the 'allocatedTime', and JSON format comes from an online service provided so I can't seem to change it. @FlyingGambit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another way to achieve the same, check if suits your requirements

Here is the fiddle: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dOxyyd

```js
var parksListJSON = {
    "for": "abcde",
    "srn": "12345678",
    "cohort": "CS/IT/JH6",
    "modules": {
        "uh6com1051": {
            "name": "Scripting"
        },
        "uh6com1063": {
            "name": "UX"
        },
        "uh6com1099": {
            "name": "Project"
        }
    },
    "schedule": [{
        "module": "uh6com1051",
        "sessionType": "lab",
        "duration": 1,
        "allocatedTime": {
            "group": "A",
            "day": "mon",
            "location": "E406",
            "time": "11"
        },
        "alternativeTimes": [{
            "group": "B",
            "day": "tues",
            "location": "E150",
            "time": "11"
        }]
    }, {
        "module": "uh6com1051",
        "sessionType": "tutorial",
        "duration": 1,
        "allocatedTime": {
            "group": "A",
            "day": "weds",
            "location": "C402",
            "time": "9"
        },
        "alternativeTimes": [{
            "group": "B",
            "day": "thurs",
            "location": "C402",
            "time": "9"
        }]
    }, {
        "module": "uh6com1051",
        "sessionType": "lecture",
        "duration": 1,
        "day": "thurs",
        "location": "B400",
        "time": "15"
    }, {
        "module": "uh6com1063",
        "sessionType": "lab",
        "duration": 1,
        "allocatedTime": {
            "group": "A",
            "day": "tues",
            "location": "E407",
            "time": "11"
        },
        "alternativeTimes": [{
            "group": "B",
            "day": "weds",
            "location": "E150",
            "time": "9"
        }, {
            "group": "C",
            "day": "thurs",
            "location": "E150",
            "time": "11"
        }]
    }, {
        "module": "uh6com1063",
        "sessionType": "tutorial",
        "duration": 1,
        "allocatedTime": {
            "group": "A",
            "day": "mon",
            "location": "C402",
            "time": "13"
        },
        "alternativeTimes": [{
            "group": "B",
            "day": "thurs",
            "location": "C400",
            "time": "9"
        }, {
            "group": "C",
            "day": "fri",
            "location": "C400",
            "time": "9"
        }]
    }, {
        "module": "uh6com1063",
        "sessionType": "lecture",
        "duration": 1,
        "day": "tues",
        "location": "A166",
        "time": "12"
    }, {
        "module": "uh6com1099",
        "sessionType": "tutorial",
        "duration": 1,
        "allocatedTime": {
            "group": "D",
            "day": "weds",
            "location": "LB252",
            "time": "11"
        },
        "alternativeTimes": [{
            "group": "A",
            "day": "mon",
            "location": "LB252",
            "time": "13"
        }, {
            "group": "B",
            "day": "mon",
            "location": "LB252",
            "time": "16"
        }, {
            "group": "C",
            "day": "tues",
            "location": "LB252",
            "time": "11"
        }, {
            "group": "E",
            "day": "thurs",
            "location": "LB252",
            "time": "11"
        }]
    }, {
        "module": "uh6com1099",
        "sessionType": "lecture",
        "duration": 1,
        "day": "fri",
        "location": "A161",
        "time": "12"
    }]
}

function displaySchedule(schedule) {
    var scheduleElement = document.getElementsByClassName("schedule");
    for (var i = 0; i < schedule.length; ++i) {
        var cellElement;
        if (schedule[i].hasOwnProperty("allocatedTime")) {
            var allocatedTime = schedule[i].allocatedTime;
            cellElement = document.querySelector("." + allocatedTime.day + " .s" + allocatedTime.time);
            cellElement.innerHTML = getModuleText(schedule[i], allocatedTime);
        }
        if (schedule[i].hasOwnProperty("alternativeTimes")) {
            for (var j = 0; j < schedule[i].alternativeTimes.length; ++j) {
                var alternativeTime = schedule[i].alternativeTimes[j];
                cellElement = document.querySelector("." + alternativeTime.day + " .s" + alternativeTime.time);
                if (cellElement.innerHTML.length > 0) {
                    cellElement.innerHTML += "<br>";
                }
                cellElement.innerHTML += getModuleText(schedule[i], alternativeTime);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Helper function
function getModuleText(schedule, scheduleTime) {
    var text = "<div class='module'>" + 
        "<span class='title'>Mod: </span>" + schedule.module + "<br>" + 
        "<span class='title'>Type: </span>" + schedule.sessionType + "<br>" + 
        "<span class='title'>Loc: </span>" + scheduleTime.location + "<br>" + 
        "<span class='title'>Group: </span>" + scheduleTime.group + 
        "</div>";
    return text;
}

displaySchedule(parksListJSON.schedule);
```

```css
/* Styles used from http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp . Check that link for info */

table.schedule {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.schedule th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
.schedule th, .schedule td {
    padding: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.schedule tr:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5
}

.schedule tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2
}

.schedule .dayRowHead, .schedule .title{
    font-weight: 500;
}

.schedule .module{
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Changed id to class -->

<table class='schedule'>
    <thead>
        <!-- Row 0-->
        <tr> 
            <th>Day</th>
            <th>09:00</th>
            <th>10:00</th>
            <th>11:00</th>
            <th>12:00</th>
            <th>13:00</th>
            <th>14:00</th>
            <th>15:00</th>
            <th>16:00</th>
            <th>17:00</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Row 1-->
        <tr class="mon">
            <td class="dayRowHead">Mon</td>
            <td class="s9"></td>
            <td class="s10"></td>
            <td class="s11"></td>
            <td class="s12"></td>
            <td class="s13"></td>
            <td class="s14"></td>
            <td class="s15"></td>
            <td class="s16"></td>
            <td class="s17"></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Row 2-->
        <tr class="tues">
             <td class="dayRowHead">Tue</td>
             <td class="s9"></td>
            <td class="s10"></td>
            <td class="s11"></td>
            <td class="s12"></td>
            <td class="s13"></td>
            <td class="s14"></td>
            <td class="s15"></td>
            <td class="s16"></td>
            <td class="s17"></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Row 3-->
        <tr class="weds">
            <td class="dayRowHead">Wed</td>
            <td class="s9"></td>
            <td class="s10"></td>
            <td class="s11"></td>
            <td class="s12"></td>
            <td class="s13"></td>
            <td class="s14"></td>
            <td class="s15"></td>
            <td class="s16"></td>
            <td class="s17"></td>
        </tr> 
        <!-- Row 3-->
        <tr class="thurs">
            <td class="dayRowHead">Thu</td> 
            <td class="s9"></td>
            <td class="s10"></td>
            <td class="s11"></td>
            <td class="s12"></td>
            <td class="s13"></td>
            <td class="s14"></td>
            <td class="s15"></td>
            <td class="s16"></td>
            <td class="s17"></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Row 4-->
        <tr class="fri">
            <td class="dayRowHead">Fri</td>
            <td class="s9"></td>
            <td class="s10"></td>
            <td class="s11"></td>
            <td class="s12"></td>
            <td class="s13"></td>
            <td class="s14"></td>
            <td class="s15"></td>
            <td class="s16"></td>
            <td class="s17"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is absolutely what I was looking for, this has helped me learn a lot, million thanks @Flying Gambit